# Why I am getting all names in one line when read from arr?

Tags: c

I have 6 names, and I would like to put them into an array

I am making it this way

```
#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 4

#define START_POINT 0

#define SETA_NAME "SETA"
#define SETB_NAME "SETB"
#define SETC_NAME "SETC"
#define SETD_NAME "SETD"
#define SETE_NAME "SETE"
#define SETF_NAME "SETF"
```

```
    char set_names_arr[COUNT_OF_SETS][LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME];

    memcpy(&set_names_arr[0][START_POINT], SETA_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);
    memcpy(&set_names_arr[1][START_POINT], SETB_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);
    memcpy(&set_names_arr[2][START_POINT], SETC_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);
    memcpy(&set_names_arr[3][START_POINT], SETD_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);
    memcpy(&set_names_arr[4][START_POINT], SETE_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);
    memcpy(&set_names_arr[5][START_POINT], SETF_NAME, LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME);

    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[0]);
    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[1]);
    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[2]);
    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[3]);
    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[4]);
    printf("\n HERE  :::  %s\n", set_names_arr[5]);
```

Here is an output

```
 HERE  :::  SETASETBSETCSETDSETESETF??v??

 HERE  :::  SETBSETCSETDSETESETF??v??

 HERE  :::  SETCSETDSETESETF??v??

 HERE  :::  SETDSETESETF??v??

 HERE  :::  SETESETF??v??

 HERE  :::  SETF??v??
```

As far as I understand I need to put `\0` this sign at the end of each line... But how to put it in my case?

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out where there should be a \0?

Comment: Also, if you want `NUL` bytes in your string, then copy them, by copying the number of 'real' characters `+ 1`, and adjust your subsequent offsets accordingly. String literals already get `NUL` at the end, so it's there for you to copy.

Comment: `#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 4` -> `#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 5`. Or use `strcpy`.

Comment: ...or zero-initialise your destination array, which is just good practice, then just copy 4 bytes into each position, leaving a 0 between each. There are plenty of ways to do this, and they're not too difficult to imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 4
```

to

```
#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 5
```

To allow for the null character at the end of the string

**EDIT**

Could do this...

```
#define LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME 5
const char set_names_arr[][LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME] = 
{
  "SETA",  
  "SETB", 
  "SETC",
  "SETD",
  "SETE",
  "SETF"
};
```

or

```
const char * const set_names_arr[] = 
{
  "SETA",  
  "SETB", 
  "SETC",
  "SETD",
  "SETE",
  "SETF"
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to init this array with my values? Or anyway I need to use this `memcpy()` method?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko See above

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko - Please look up the use of `const`

Answer (score 2):

Memcpy has following signature:

```
     void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/):  Copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed to by source directly to the memory block pointed to by destination.

This you need to calculate length of each `SET_NAME` and put it's `length + 1` inside `num` param of memcpy. Please note that `sizeof(SET_NAME)` = `5` i.e four characters and one byte for `\0` character.

```
memcpy(&set_names_arr[0][START_POINT], SETA_NAME, sizeof(SETA_NAME));
```

Update : 
Since we need `5` bytes for each SET_NAME, we need to allocate `5` bytes for each `SET_NAME` like this:

```
  char set_names_arr[COUNT_OF_SETS][5];
```

Another way to do this is already answered. See Ed heal's answer. He's using Pre-processor Macros - which is just string replacement to set it to 5.

Comment: It is also worth noting that `sizeof()` does not "calculate" anything. It works in this case because the string literal has a length known at compile time and is an array of chars, which `sizeof` returns the total array size. However, it would very much _not_ work if just given a pointer to a string of `char`s, which "calculate" may imply. In that case we only get the `sizeof` the memory address in that pointer. So, it wouldn't work for strings whose length can't be known at runtime, without calling a function to count through their bytes until reaching a `NUL`.

Comment: So, would you say we should prefer `strlen + 1` over `sizeof` ?

Comment: `sizeof(string_literal)` is fine, but `sizeof(some_random_char_star)` is not. So it's about knowing which code does the right thing in which context. Yes, `std::strlen()` will work in both cases, but for char arrays whose size is known at compile time, it's a waste of cycles.

Comment: But, `strlen(string_literal)` and `sizeof(string_literal)`, both will be converted to constants by modern compiler, thereby reducing any real need of `sizeof`.

Comment: But when I try this `memcpy(&set_names_arr[0][START_POINT], SETA_NAME, sizeof(SETA_NAME));` I get `'memcpy' will always overflow; destination buffer has size 4, but size
      argument is 5`

Comment: @E.N.D They might. Have you tested that indeed every "modern compiler" does that? If so, great! I still don't think `std::strlen()` and its `#include` are needed for string literals / char arrays. But sure, if you want to be safe, with whatever risk of possibly counting characters when we don't need to, go ahead; safety is preferable to what might be premature optimisation.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You mentioned `LENGTH_OF_SET_NAME` is 4, later on. Updating my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to init this array with my values? Or anyway I need to use this memcpy() method?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Nope, Use this : `char *set_names_arr[COUNT_OF_SETS]  =  { "SETA", "SETB"  , "SETC" , "SETD" , "SETE" , "SETF"}; `

Comment: Perhaps `const char * const set_names_arrs[] = ...` would be better. See my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to have zeroes at the end of every string.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko You copied 4 bytes from each string, but the strings are actually 5 bytes including the null byte.

Comment: Yes. Exactly at the end of **every** string. The size of "1234" is 5 because of that terminating zero